# Google Vision API normalize image

Tags: php, image-processing, ocr, google-vision

I'm using Google Vison API with PHP.

I want to analyze image and extract table data from it.

The image will not always be aligned or in the same size.

I've got reference image which I'm looking for words that I know will always be there and then I'm trying to compare to the current image and fix positions

For each word I've got the bounds(top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left)

I've draw the bounds of the words.
reference image => red,
current image => green
[image]

Next I've compared the top red and green rectangles and shift them all based on the differences.
adjusted image => cyan.
[image]

The top one is correct because he was the reference. the others just shift but the distance between them are not correct.

What is the best practice to normalize the image based on reference image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The API returns the height and width: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageResponse#page

You could use those numbers and the numbers from your golden image to know how much to shift the boxes.